# Visual Studio, Find and replace, regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2005, replace

I am trying to replace all the `#include "whatever.h"` with `#include <whatever.h>` using find and replace functionality in Visual Studio 2005. I used the regex `\#include \"[a-z\.h]+\"` to find the include statement. But I am wondering how frame the replace regex.

`\#include \<[a-z\.h]+\>` did not work and won't; it replaces the statement `#include "whatever.h"` with `#include <[a-z.h]+>`. How shall I frame the replace regex to retain `whatever.h` as it is?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

**For versions *before* Visual studio 2012:**
It works when I do this:
find `include "{[a-zA-Z]+\.h}"`,
replace with `include <\1>`.
The most relevant parts for your question are the curly braces `{}` and the back reference `\1`: `\n` references to the n'th group indicated by curly braces in the search expression.

**For versions Visual studio 2012 & up:**
Starting with VS2012 .NET Framework regular expressions are used. So there it should be:
find `include "([a-zA-Z]+\.h)"`,
replace with `include <$1>`.

Comment: This seems to differ from the standard regular expressions syntax which uses parentheses for this functionality.

Comment: It is now different in Visual Studio 2012.  $1 should be used instead of \1.  () now replaces {}.  More consistant with everyone else now.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to capture more filenames.

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible with the short version:

[image: Short version]

https://regex101.com/r/vW7Rbh/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to select both Match Case and Regular Expressions for regex expressions with case.
Else [a-z] won't work.[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is my use case I need to find all the html comments like this

```
<!--begin::Info-->
<!--End::Info-->
```

this is what I used

**((<!--.+?-->)|('.+?'))**

I hope it can be helpful for someone

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.