# Search and replace in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

In Visual Studio, when I search within a selection, I want to replace the first instance (or second, third, etc.) of a match per line using regular expressions. How would I do this?

Search and replace

```
foo1 = foo1;
foo2 = foo2;
...
foo20 = foo20;
```

into the following.

```
foo1 = bar1;
foo2 = bar2;
...
foo20 = bar20;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In **Visual Studio 2010 and earlier**, use regular expressions with back references

Visual Studio's regular expressions are completely different from what I've learned. Took me some time to figure out the correct answer.

Search for

```
{foo}{:d+} = \1\2
```

Replace with

```
\1\2 = bar\2
```

Back references are done by `tagging` with curly braces `{foo}`. `:d+` is the same for `\d+`

[Read more about VS RegEx here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Would this regex not return? bar1 = bar1; bar2 = bar2; ... bar20 = bar20;

Comment: Nope it wouldn't. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you edited your Post? I remember an other version. This one is okay =)

Comment: i would rather not use digits in my regex. for example i might want to replace `redMonkey = redMonkey` with `redMonkey = blueMonkey`

Comment: Oh well, then it's just a matter of dropping the digit `:d+` from the regex :). And please clearly state your requirements. Do you know what `foo` is beforehand, or you just to search for `foo = foo` where you don't know what foo is ?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray: I would drop the first part, with the "standard" regex solution.  Or move it to the bottom--but by all means keep the part about the VS regex flavor being, um, *unique*. ;)

Comment: IN VS2013 this doesnt work at all. I have to replace curly {} with round () and it works.

Comment: @ppumkin Same with VS 2012 for me.

Comment: What the heck is this syntax?!

Answer (score 84):

In Visual Studio 2012, capture groups and backreferences are used just like in C#. You can capture them with common parenthesis, and backreference them with $0, $1, etc. Hope it helps!

Note that the syntax `$1` is used for find-replace, but `\1` is used for backreferences in the search string.

Comment: I was about to draw the conclusion that backreferences had been removed from Visual Studio 2012 until I read this answer. It is not mentioned at all in the official documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just to elaborate with an example for VS 2012, a reg. exp. for removing the surrounding quotes from text elements in an XML document:

_Find box_: **>"(.*)"<**

_Replace box_: **>$1<**

Comment: Huzzah for proper regular expressions in VS 2012! This is huge!

Comment: Used for find-replace in VS2019 and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

I can be done without a regular expression as well:

Replace `= foo` with `= bar`.

If a regular expression is needed, one could use:

```
foo(\d*) = foo(\d*);
```

Replace with:

```
foo\1 = bar\2;
```

Comment: This wouldn't actually work because `\d` is not an accepted character in Visual Studio.

Comment: Backreferences for replacing need to use `$1`, not `\1`, in vs 2012 at least.

Comment: This is for older, pre-2012 versions of Visual Studio. For newer versions see the answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147096/visual-studio-find-and-replace-regex/3147177#3147177

Answer (score 3):

Here it is, type exactly as it is displayed here

Search: `(\w+\d+\s*=\s*)[^\d]+(\d+);`

Replace: `$1bar$2;`

---

Read more: [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this in Visual Studio 2019 Find/Replace.
I needed to replace FORTRAN IO format string to C++ format and used sub-expression and numbers of regexp.

Example:   find:   "f9.8", "f18.3", in line and    replace  with %9.8f, %18.3f
             reg exp:  Find = ( f)(\d+.\d+)   Replace = %$2f

Answer (score -2):

If you would be more variable:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\= )[^;0-9]*(?=[0-9]*;)", replacewith);
```

This search for `=` and `(anynumber);` and replace that between.

**Edit:**
The number is optional.

Comment: This question is about using the Find/Replace module of Visual Studio, not about VB.