# Visual Studio 2012 Regexes

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I have read

1. [MSDN Documentation on Regular Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx)
2. Stack Overflow question *[Search and replace in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848329)*

But these did not help me.

I want to match the simplest string in the entire universe, "0:n", "1:n", "2:n", etc. I have tried the following [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) regular expression.

```
{:d+}:n
```

This does not return any results (and there are results). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been looking at documentation for outdated versions of Visual Studio.

[Starting with VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the "standard" regex syntax is supported, more precisely the [.NET flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

So, for your example, the regex would be `\d+:n\b`.

Comment: Yeah, always be sure to check near the top of the MSDN page for the version the doc applies to. To the right of that version there is typically a link that permits you to switch to a different version of VS. The doc may or may not change depending on what MS changed from version to version.