# Replace string with regex and keep some of its content

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

In my code, I have statements like this:

```
 Project.MVC.Bll.Resources.<resource-name>
```

And I want to replace them with

```
 ProjectResources.GetString("<resouce-name>")
```

I want to use the visual studio Find And Replace with regular expression, but the problem is that I don't know how to "take" the resource-name.

For the search pattern I'm using `Project.MVC.Bll.Resources.*` , but I have no idea what the replacement pattern will be, in order to put the resource name in the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct you're looking for is called [captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (or sometimes capture groups).  There's an example of how to do that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2003/05/24/7498.aspx).  There also looks to be an MSDN page on exactly this topic: [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx) with an example of using numbered captures.

Also worth pointing out that earlier versions of Visual Studio used [slightly different syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7848502/164966) for this.

In your case the capture will probably look something like

```
Project\.MVC\.Bll\.Resources\.(?<name>____)
```

and the replacement along the lines of

```
ProjectResources.GetString("${name}")
```

Just replace `____` with whatever pattern your resource names follow.  Also don't forget that `.` means *any character* in RegEx, so you need to escape them to only match periods.

Comment: +1.  "Slightly different syntax" isn't quite how I would have described it. ;)  Good to know they finally made the switch.

Comment: @AlanMoore If you squint hard enough `{` almost looks like `(`.  I think that and the `:(d|w|forget what else)` were the main differences.