# How to use regular expression in visual studio 2017 for find and replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2017

I have script tags everywhere in CSHML files. Something like below

```
<script src="~/Areas/Users/Somefilename.js"></script>
```

Using the regular expression i want to replace it using Visual Studio 2017 find and replace with the following

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Users/Somefilename.js")
```

The path parameter remains the same.

So based on the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147096/visual-studio-find-and-replace-regex)

In find box i put `<script src=.*></script>`
and in replace box i put `@Scripts.Render($1)`

it finds the line in cshtml but replace does not work. It actually puts `$1` instead of the path. `@Scripts.Render($1)`

Comment: You did not define a capturing group, use `<script src=(".*?")></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap you `.*` in brackets like this `(.*)`. This will [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the value and enable the replacement.